# How to check if django form data is None, ' ' (empty string), or False

Tags: python, django, forms, field

```
if form.data['first_name'] is None:
    return True
else: 
   return False
```

I'm trying to check if this first_name field is blank or "None". But if the field happens to be blank the following will return ( u'' ) along with false.  Any other solution for determining if this specific form field is blank or none? And why this happens?

Comment: You should be checking `form.cleaned_data`, not `form.data`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that by checking for:

```
 if form.data['first_name'] is None:
```

you only check if the value is None, whereas:

```
if not form.data['first_name']:
```

checks for `None` or `''` an empty string or `False` come to that.

What you could also do is:

```
return bool(form.data.get('first_name', False))
```

In this case if `form.data['first_name']` is not present it will `return False`, if the value is `None` or `''` this will also `return False`, if the value is `True` or `'a string'` it will `return True`.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do:

```
if form.data['first_name']:
```

`is None` specifically checks for `None`.

Comment: ah! Thanks, I've done that before but was having such a mind block

Answer (score 1):

or do the following:-

```
if not form.data['first_name']:
```

or

```
firstname=FormData.getvalue('first_name')
if not firstname:
   <then let people know this shouldn't be empty or None>
```